# How can I set focus to the slickgrid control on my page to enable keyboard navigation?

Tags: javascript, events, slickgrid

Keyboard navigation on my slickgrid is working great, but when the page loads, the user has to click on the grid to get the up and down arrows to start navigating the rows, which defeats the purpose. How can I set focus to the control on page load?

I tried:

```
$('#id_of_container_div').focus();
$('.slick-row:first').focus();
```

No dice :/

Comment: Chris, seriously, why would you even want to do this!?!??!

Comment: $('.slick-row:first').click() ? :) not sure, really, but who knows

Comment: @GoinAum to reduce the potential for RSI to injure my user, same as any other keyboard-centric UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

```
$('.slick-cell:first').click();
```